# Where is the space in my SD card?

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I just got a raspberry pi. It came with an 8GB SD card (actually an SD adapter + microsd card) with the RPi logo on it.

It supposed to have 8Gb, but "parted" command says something different ...

```
$ sudo parted
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/mmcblk0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) help                                                             
  align-check TYPE N                        check partition N for TYPE(min|opt) alignment
  check NUMBER                             do a simple check on the file system
  cp [FROM-DEVICE] FROM-NUMBER TO-NUMBER   copy file system to another partition
  help [COMMAND]                           print general help, or help on COMMAND
  mklabel,mktable LABEL-TYPE               create a new disklabel (partition table)
  mkfs NUMBER FS-TYPE                      make a FS-TYPE file system on partition NUMBER
  mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END     make a partition
  mkpartfs PART-TYPE FS-TYPE START END     make a partition with a file system
  move NUMBER START END                    move partition NUMBER
  name NUMBER NAME                         name partition NUMBER as NAME
  print [devices|free|list,all|NUMBER]     display the partition table, available devices, free space, all found partitions, or a particular partition
  quit                                     exit program
  rescue START END                         rescue a lost partition near START and END
  resize NUMBER START END                  resize partition NUMBER and its file system
  rm NUMBER                                delete partition NUMBER
  select DEVICE                            choose the device to edit
  set NUMBER FLAG STATE                    change the FLAG on partition NUMBER
  toggle [NUMBER [FLAG]]                   toggle the state of FLAG on partition NUMBER
  unit UNIT                                set the default unit to UNIT
  version                                  display the version number and copyright information of GNU Parted
(parted) print                                                            
Model: SD USD (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 8069MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  62.9MB  58.7MB  primary  fat16        lba
 2      62.9MB  3277MB  3214MB  primary  ext4
```

And I'm running out space ...

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       2.9G  2.7G   50M  99% /
devtmpfs        428M     0  428M   0% /dev
tmpfs            87M  228K   87M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           173M     0  173M   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1   56M   20M   37M  36% /boot
```

Where are the other 4.5 Gb left ?

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Raspbian.

1. `sudo raspi-config`
2. Choose option #1 : `Expand filesystem`
3. `Tab` `Tab` ---> select `finish` ---> Reboot ? `yes`
4. After reboot. Run `df -h`

For more info on raspi-config. Go through [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md)

## A debian based OS other than Raspbian (ubuntu, debian armhf, etc)

`raspi-config` is not available by default on an OS other than `raspbian`.

1. `wget http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20150706_all.deb`
2. `sudo gdebi raspi-config_20150706_all.deb`

It will install `raspi-config` along with its dependancies. Now follow raspbian steps as mentioned above to expand file system.

## Any Linux distribution (works for Raspbian as well)

Follow this wiki page : http://elinux.org/RPi_Resize_Flash_Partitions#Manually_resizing_the_SD_card_on_Linux

It very well explains how to use `parted` to expand file system.

Hope it helps.

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!   $ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       7.3G  2.7G  4.3G  39% /