# Install Opencv on an external Hard Drive

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive, opencv

I am new to the raspberry world.

I was trying to install opencv on my raspberry pi 2 and when I give the command:

```
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.0.0.zip
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot write to 'opencv.zip' (No space left on device).
```

Do you know if is it possible to mount, compile and run opencv on an external hard drive?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Why don't you expand SD card file system ?

Comment: What do you mean? How do you do it?

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33785/where-is-the-space-in-my-sd-card/33786#33786 Follow the first part of the answer.